# Can pg_dump be instructed to create tables with "IF NOT EXISTS"?

Tags: sql, postgresql, pg-dump

As per the title.

I've looked at the man page and it doesn't seem like there is any command-line argument to include the "IF NOT EXISTS" clause in the "CREATE TABLE" statements.

Comment: There isn't. If you want to do that, wrap it in a `DO` block that checks `information_schema` to see if the table exists. The reason why is that `IF NOT EXISTS` has no way to handle the case where a completely different table with the same name exists.

Comment: This is no good reason imo. if there is a table with completely different columns then it should be named differently. So imo an IF NOT EXISTS would make sense

Answer (score 13):

No. The closest that *pg_dump* comes to this in terms of a built-in option is `--if-exists`, which only works in conjunction with `--clean`, meaning it **only** applies to things like `DROP` commands.

If you want to add this sort of thing, I think your best bet would be to *post-process* the dumps (assuming you are dumping to pure *SQL* and not binary format). To cover all the variety of cases, you would technically need a regex that covers this portion of the [`CREATE TABLE`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createtable.html) command grammar:

```
CREATE [ [ GLOBAL | LOCAL ] { TEMPORARY | TEMP } | UNLOGGED ] TABLE
       [ IF NOT EXISTS ] table_name
```

However a simpler regex will likely cover most cases (for example, I don't think you'd ever be dumping temp tables, pretty much definitionally, so that part can be ignored). Similarly, `GLOBAL` and `LOCAL` are deprecated, so those can perhaps also be safely ignored, depending on your data.

[pg_dump doc](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-pgdump.html) for reference.