# Rails: permission denied for relation schema_migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, apache2

I'm trying to setup a local production environment for a Ruby on Rails web application. I can run the application with `rails server` command, which gives the development environment.

The production environment I'm trying to set up is purely local and I've followed this tutorial for setting it up with apache 2: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-setup-a-rails-4-app-with-apache-and-passenger-on-centos-6

However when I go to the page of my application I get the following error:

```
PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_migrations : SELECT "schema_migrations".* FROM "schema_migrations"
```

in my database.yml I have these settings for development and production:

```
adapter: postgresql
database: whiteboard
username:
password:
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

I'm not allowed to change these settings, no matter what.

Is there any way to fix this? (if yes, step by step please)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems you have to create a DB user with all needed privileges on your DB.
For example I think you could do the trick by log in your DB console then do something like:

```
CREATE USER your_new_username WITH PASSWORD 'your_new_password';
CREATE DATABASE whiteboard;
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE whiteboard to your_new_username;
ALTER DATABASE whiteboard OWNER TO your_new_username;
```

Then update you `database.yml` like this:

```
adapter: postgresql
database: whiteboard
username: your_new_username
password: your_new_password
pool: 5
timeout: 5000
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: I cannot change the database.yml file, unfortunately. If the other team got things running with this file, it should be possible. Any idea If making an empty user is possible?

Comment: May be they were using solution like capistrano to deploy the code.
You should take a look on the great Railscasts about setup a VPS for a Rails app http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps

Comment: I forgot why, but I tried `GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON DATABASE whiteboard TO nobody` and now the application runs! Apparently somewhere I made a user nobody for apache. I'll look into the link you posted as well, It'll probably be a much better solution.

Comment: Good to here, even if I'm not sure it's the best way to have a bullet proof environment. I'd suggest you to learn more about how to setup a production environment, Capistrano is quiet simple to learn and can be a game changer for you, even if it's not the only choice you have, it's used by a lot of people in production.

Comment: I did this and my postgres keeps on giving this same error. Could you please take a look at [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41424654/postgres-permission-denied-for-relation-schema-migrations)

Answer (score 0):

I was using dbmate which also creates a table called schema_migrations on startup, and thus fails when a full dump is applied that also has the same table. Here are a few approaches

1. PostgreSQL doesn't support creating dump with IF NOT EXISTS, unlike mysql:

See [Can pg_dump be instructed to create tables with "IF NOT EXISTS"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30880537/can-pg-dump-be-instructed-to-create-tables-with-if-not-exists)

2. However, PostgreSQL 9.1 and newer supports CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS -syntax, so you could string replace the dump for example by using sed:

   sed -i 's/CREATE TABLE/CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS/g' dump.sql
3. But in practice, I ended to delete the lines from the dump with schema_migrations on it, and +1-2 lines following:

   sed -i '/CREATE TABLE public.schema_migrations (/,+2 d' dump.sql

   sed -i '/ALTER TABLE ONLY public.schema_migrations/,+1 d' dump.sql