# ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (PG::InsufficientPrivilege: ERROR: permission denied for relation schema_migrations

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, activerecord

While I am trying to perform the post operation in Ruby on Rails application, I am getting the above error. User postgres is already having all the required to privileges to perform the operation.

Comment: Check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/q/38271376/2334082